# How to use WPF ContentControl 's content with DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol

I copied some resource about custom button using Content control. And I changed something to be `<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContentControl},Path=Content}">` For the dataTempalte

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PriceDataTemplate" DataType="m:ClickTradeViewModel">
    <Button Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}" Cursor="Hand">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF345C8B" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExecuting}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>

        <UserControl>
            <UserControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContentControl},Path=Content}"></TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </UserControl.Template>
        </UserControl>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

And for the actual Button, it used

```
<ContentControl x:Name="AskContentControl" Grid.Column="2" 
                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                Content="{Binding QQ.Bid}" 
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PriceDataTemplate}"/>
```

I expect the `Content` will use `double Bid`'s `tostring` method to render the content, but it shows nothing inside (gray color). In the plot the left side shows the price did exists.

[image]

**Update**: I am not sure what's going on, but with some change `<TextBlock Text="{Binding QQ.Ask}"></TextBlock>` and set

```
<ContentControl x:Name="AskContentControl" Grid.Column="2" 
                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                Content="{Binding}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PriceDataTemplate}"/> makes it work.
```

The problem is then I had to explicitly set the `PriceDataTemplate` several times for different properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are using a Binding with RelativeSource finding a `ContentControl` but `UserControl` is also a `ContentControl`, so what it found is actually the `UserControl`, not the root `ContentControl` you thought. In this case you can specify some `AncestorLevel` as `2` (to find the second `ContentControl`):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding 
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                           AncestorType=ContentControl, AncestorLevel=2},
           Path=Content}"></TextBlock>
```

However it's not really safe and in this case the implicit DataContext is actually the `Content` you set for your `ContentControl` (this `DataContext` flows down from the `DataTemplate` through the UserControl's Template). So the Binding can be just simple like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
```

Note I supposed you keep setting the ContentControl's Content to `{Binding QQ.Bid}`.

Comment: The second simple way works! But using `AncestorLevel` only renders a `Windows.Controls` result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a full working solution... I'm late but perhaps it could help others?

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ParametricStudyAnalysis.ScopeSelection.Special"
             xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid" x:Class="ParametricStudyAnalysis.ScopeSelection.Special.UserControlAddSpecialSignal"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:UserControlAddSpecialSignalModel></local:UserControlAddSpecialSignalModel>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserControlSpecialSignalTtrModel}">
            <local:UserControlSpecialSignalTtr/>
        </DataTemplate>     
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <GroupBox Header="Signal type" Grid.Row="0" Padding="5">
            <xcdg:DataGridControl Name="DataGrid" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding SpecialSignalEntries}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SpecialSignalEntrySelected}" Height="200">
            <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
                <xcdg:Column FieldName="Name" Title="Type of special signal" ReadOnly="True"></xcdg:Column>
            </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Parameters" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,3,0,0" Padding="5">
            <ContentControl Name="MyContentControl" 
                            DataContext="{Binding SpecialSignalEntrySelected, Mode=OneWay}" 
                            Content="{Binding SignalProviderSpecial}">
            </ContentControl>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```